# How to add validations in selenium web driver, if the element was not found

Tags: java, selenium

How to add validations in selenium web driver, if the element or ID was not found(using 'if')

Comment: Actually if element is not found it should throw exception so you know you can handle it with try-catch block. If you want to more help please specify your question with a piece of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the element you are trying to identify is present or not.

Put the element you are trying to identify in the try block. If you get NoSuchElementException, it means element is not present.

Catch the exception.

```
    public void isPresent()
    {
       try
       {
            driver.findElement(By.id("elementID"));
            System.out.println("element is present");
       }
       catch ( Exception e )
       {
            System.out.println("Element is not present");
            return;
       }
    }
```

This way you can handle the exception.